Why I am getting two values for $\lim_{z\to\frac {2-i}{5}} \frac{z - \frac{2-i}{5}}{(1-2i)z^2 + 6iz -1-2i}$?
I was trying to evaluate the limit $\lim_{z\to\frac {2-i}{5}} \frac{z - \frac{2-i}{5}}{(1-2i)z^2 + 6iz -1-2i}$. But I got two answers in two approaches.
Approach 1
$(1-2i)z^2 + 6iz -1-2i = (z - \frac {2-i}{5})(z - (2-i))$
So, $\lim_{z\to\frac {2-i}{5}} \frac{z - \frac{2-i}{5}}{(1-2i)z^2 + 6iz -1-2i} = \lim_{z\to\frac {2-i}{5}} \frac{z - \frac{2-i}{5}}{(z - \frac {2-i}{5})(z - (2-i))} = \lim_{z\to\frac {2-i}{5}} \frac{1}{(z - (2-i))} = - \frac{1}{2}-\frac{i}{4}$
Approach 2
Using L'Hôpital's rule,
$\lim_{z\to\frac {2-i}{5}} \frac{z - \frac{2-i}{5}}{(1-2i)z^2 + 6iz -1-2i} = \lim_{z\to\frac {2-i}{5}}\frac{1}{2z(1-2i)+6i} = -\frac{i}{4}$
What is wrong here? Am I missing any theoretical detail here?

Your factorization in first approach is wrong. In fact, none of the coefficients match!

In the first one you missed the leading coefficient

When you use the quadratic equation to factorize $ax^2+bx+c$ with to roots $x_1,x_2$ it will be like $$ax^2+bx+c=a(x-x_1)(x-x_2)$$ so $$(1-2i)z^2 + 6iz -1-2i=0\\z_1,z_2=\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}=\\\frac {-6i\pm\sqrt{(6i)^2-4(1-2i)(-1-2i)}}{2(1-2i)}=\\\frac {-6i\pm\sqrt{-16}}{2(1-2i)}=\frac {-6i\pm 4i}{2(1-2i)}$$so $$(1-2i)z^2 + 6iz -1-2i=(1-2i)(z-z_1)(z-z_2)$$ as they said, you miss $1-2i$

What a silly mistake! Wasted a lot of my time. By the way, Thank you very much.

All of us make mistakes sometimes

Don't carry the limit operator during calculation, instead carry out simplifying operations first and then find the limit.
The way to go is to set $z=\frac{2-i}5+w$ with $w\to 0$
The denominator becomes
$\begin{align}(1-2i)z^2+6iz-1-2i &=(1-2i)(\tfrac{2-i}5+w)^2+6i(\tfrac{2-i}5+w)-1-2i\\
&=4iw+(1-2i)w^2
\end{align}$
Therefore $f(z)=\dfrac{w}{4iw+(1-2i)w^2}=\dfrac{1}{4i+\underbrace{(1-2i)w}_{\to\ 0}}\to \dfrac 1{4i}=-\frac 14i$
So you probably made a calculation error in approach 1.
